# what is the Proper korean word to say Hello?

Tags: korean-to-english

what is the Proper korean word to say Hello.. i hard many different words saying hello like below.

1. Anyaseyo
2. anyo

so what is the correct word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in any language, there are lots of ways to greet people. I think the two you mean are:

- **Annyeong haseyo?** (안녕하세요?). This literally means 'are you in peace?', but idiomatically is a polite way of saying 'hello'.
- **Annyeong!** (안녕!). This is a more informal, shorter version. You can think of it as being the equivalent of 'Hi!'.

The shorter version, 'Annyeong!', can also be used between close friends to mean 'Bye!'. However, to say 'bye' in a more polite way, you might say

*Annyeonghi Gyeseyo* (안녕히 계세요) - 'stay in peace', if the other person is staying, or 
 *Annyeonghi Gaseyo* (안녕히 가세요) 'go in peace', if the other person is leaving.

I'm mentioning these as, when said fast, they can sound like 'annyeong haseyo?' - but you wouldn't use 'annyeong haseyo?' to say goodbye.

Comment: I can't make an edit to the answer as it'll be too short, but the Romaja transcription of 가세요 should be *Kaseyo*.

Comment: Actually, according to the Revised Romanization law(set by 국립국어원(the National Institute of Korean Language)), 가세요 IS written as Gaseyo......

Comment: I think @drooze wrote like above according to the McCune–Reischauer Romanization, but that was only used till the early 21st century.....

Comment: @J.Y.Park So, I was following the answer's Romanisation scheme to remain consistent, as otherwise following 國立國語院's Romanisation scheme would lead to *Gyeseyo* for **계세요**.

Comment: @droooze thank you for respecting my non-standard Romanisation - I don't really like 'g' for 'ㄱ' - but I guess standard is better and I've accepted J. Y. Park's edit :)